# Limit visibility to subclasses only in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, visibility

In Java, the `protected` keyword limits the visibility of a field or method to the subclasses *and the whole package*.

Is there a way to limit the visibility only to subclasses, in a static way (i.e. at compilation time, without integrating runtime access control logic within the method)? In other words, is there a way to simulate the behaviour of a (friendless) C++-like `protected` modifier?

Comment: C++ : "Where `friend`s have access to your `private` members".

Answer (score 3):

No, unfortunately there isn't any. As you have said, `protected` gives access *also* to classes in the same package.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : no. Just exclude of the package the classes you don't want to be able to see the methods.

Comment: Why a downvote ? The answer is as valid as the other one